# How can I tag a Docker image as I'm building it with stack?

Tags: docker, haskell-stack

I'd like to build Docker images for my Stack project as part of my CI, where the tag matches the branch and revision.

So, something like this:

```
stack image container --tag $(./image-tag)
```

Where `./image-tag` is a script that generates a tag like `master-a1b2c3d`. The name of the image is always the same, but the tag varies.

My `stack.yaml` has the following stanza:

```
image:
  container:
    base: fpco/haskell-scratch:integer-gmp
    name: jml0/my-image
```

Building with `stack image container --image my-image:foo` creates an image, but it's not tagged `foo`.